# Geth returning balance 0

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, balances, geth-debugging, fast-sync

I started my geth using fast sync first and then normal sync once it was almost synced. 'currentBlock' is not increasing since hour and 'highestBlock' keep on increasing.

**geth --testnet --rpc --cache=1024 --syncmode "fast" --rpcapi eth,web3,net,ssh,db,debug,personal --rpcaddr "10.128.0.4" --rpcport "8545"**

**geth attach ipc:/home/blockhealth/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc**

```
> web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5950072,
  highestBlock: 5950187,
  knownStates: 32304159,
  pulledStates: 32290607,
  startingBlock: 5949969
}
```

I started my geth using --**testnet** i.e, on **ropsten**.

I checked that the block which includes the transaction of transferring the ETH from other wallet to my wallet is also added to the GETH. 
On https://ropsten.etherscan.io balance is 1.5ETH in my wallet.
But still I am seeing balance as 0 when checking with geth :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xXXXXXX')
0
```

And error **'Insufficient funds for gas * price + value'** while connecting to my smart contract.

my GETH version is : **Geth/v1.8.27-stable-4bcc0a37/linux-amd64/go1.10.4**

Comment: what's the result of eth.blockNumber

Comment: web3.eth.blockNumber = 0

Comment: You get these results because you are still syncing, so you need to wait longer. I don't know the total number of `pulledStates` of Ropsten but on Rinkeby is around 90697511.

Comment: My node is getting synced from 12hours. From last 6hours there is a lag of 50-120 blocks.

Comment: I didn't got the solution there. Nothing worked for me

Comment: I got it, Unless geth is fully synced, it does not give these details